# Python - Searching a hyphen in a given string

Tags: python, regex

I tried using the following line to print true if a hyphen is found in a string:

```
print (re.match('-', 'p-abcd-abcd'))
```

Instead of 'true', 'None' is printed.

Answer (score 3):

`re.match` will match the pattern from the start of the string. If you want  to search a pattern within a string You need `re.search()`:

```
re.search(r'-', 'p-abcd-abcd')
```

But if you just want to check the membership of a character in a string,you can simply use `in` operand :

```
if '-' in 'p-abcd-abcd'
```